# How to derive the following pattern with Python

Tags: python

How can I make the following pattern with Python, I thought about everything, but I didn't get anywhere

[image]

> Problem solved, thanks to all contributors

Why negativity?

Well, if stackoverflow is not for asking questions, then what is it for???

Comment: looks like exersise from codecool,com What solutions did you tried? Did you have solve it in other languange?

Answer (score 0):

The displayed numbers are always the maximum of the row number and column number they appear at.

So, to print that pattern, you could do something line this:

```
def solve(n):
    for row in range(1, n + 1):
        for col in range(1, n + 1):
            print(max(row, col), end=" ")
        print("\n")

solve(5)
```

As you posted an image, it is not clear whether there should be empty lines between the lines with numbers, and whether at the end it is fine to have trailing newline characters or not.

Also check whether there are requirements as to how the pattern should look when the size of the matrix is more than 9.

But it should not be hard to adapt the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    for j in range(i):
        numbers[j] += 1
    print(*numbers)
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 2 3 4 5
3 3 3 4 5
4 4 4 4 5
5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np #Just to format as matrix when printing

a=[[max(r,c) for r in range(1,6)] for c in range(1,6)]
print(np.array(a))

>>> [[1 2 3 4 5]
>>>  [2 2 3 4 5]
>>>  [3 3 3 4 5]
>>>  [4 4 4 4 5]
>>>  [5 5 5 5 5]]
```